# An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong

Tags: apt, permissions, notification

recently I have been getting this error message, it just come up in my notification.

(An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was: ' Error: Opening the cache (E:can not open /var/lib/apt/lists/ archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease -fopen (13: Permission denied), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies)

can you guys help me to fix it? I have searched before but nothing.

Comment: Open a terminal, and run `sudo apt -f install`. Edit the question to post the output. https://askubuntu.com/posts/1434579/edit

Comment: thank you!! problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt install -f` in a terminal to install the missing dependencies.